# django-social-auth: How can I implement more provider?

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I need to ask different permission at facebook login:

- **publish_stream** and **emails** for standard users
- **publish_stream**, **emails** and **manage_pages** for "admin" users

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732183/django-social-auth-split-what-permissions-are-asked-for-from-facebook), the library's author tell that I have to define a new backend/provider. But how can I do that?

I don't understand how can I do that. Can someone explain me what I've to do step-by-step?

Comment: How do you know if they're an admin if they're not logged in?

Comment: If any user is logged in, this is an "admin" user. Then I want to associate his facebbok account as described before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A backend like this should do the work:

```
from social_auth.backends.facebook import FacebookAuth, FacebookBackend

class FacebookBackendForAdmins(FacebookBackend):
    name = 'facebook-admins'

class FacebookAuthForAdmins(FacebookAuth):
    AUTH_BACKEND = FacebookBackendForAdmins
    SCOPE_VAR_NAME = 'FACEBOOK_ADMIN_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS'
```

Then define the setting:

```
FACEBOOK_ADMIN_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email', 'publish_stream', 'manage_pages']
```

And don't forget the setting for non-admin users:

```
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email', 'publish_stream']
```

And also add it to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting (assuming that you add that code into `yourapp/facebook_backend_for_admins.py`):

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    ...
    'yourapp.facebook_backend_for_admins.FacebookBackendForAdmins',
    ...
)
```

Comment: It doesn't work! I've to add `BACKENDS = {
    'facebook-page': FacebookAppAuth if USE_APP_AUTH else FacebookPagesAuth,
}` after the FacebookAuthForAdmins class